# ElasticSearch: Is it possible to give a lower score for fuzziness?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running a multi_match (with most_fields and "fuzziness": "AUTO") query for "Rob", but I get a result with "Ron" before "Rob".

If I remove the fuzziness, it shows Rob only, not Ron. However, I do want to use the fuzziness, I just expect all results that are exact match to be more relevant and to be shown first. It's not happening.
Investigating the 'explain', shows that the IDF of 'Ron' is a bit higher.

Back to my question - is it possible to configure some 'boost' or 'score' to the fuzziness element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I ended up with the following based on what suggested here:
https://medium.com/@oysterpail/fuzzy-queries-ae47b66b325c#.a4uxw5z0b

Their solution is using a `bool` query of `should`. I can't do it as I need this part of the query to be `must` (I use the `should` part for relevancy), and a bool query of `must` is actually `AND`. However, `must` + `or` did the trick:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "or":[
               {
                  "multi_match":{
                     "query":"rob",
                     "fields":[
                        "username",
                        "firstName",
                        "lastName"
                     ],
                     "type":"most_fields",
                     "fuzziness":"AUTO"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "multi_match":{
                     "query":"rob",
                     "fields":[
                        "username",
                        "firstName",
                        "lastName"
                     ],
                     "type":"most_fields"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This way, the results coming from the `fuzziness` part, have a match only to the first part of the query, whereas the exact-match results have a match to both parts, therefore they are showing up first.

Comment: That is a creative solution, but also hacky in some way, and wouldn't this cost more computation time? I 'd be curious to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Not sure why, but when using with MultiMatch, fields that match using fuzziness automatically have about 80% lower scores.

Answer (score 1):

quite an old question but I'll answer to help others looking at it in the present.
Well the reason you are getting 'Ron' before 'Rob' is because of the TF/IDF algorithm. In your dataset the word 'Rob' has more occurrence than 'Ron' so the algorithm will give a lower score to 'Rob'.

If you just want to search for names then you can use a different scoring algorithm or [similarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity). In your case a 'boolean' similarity should work.

Comment: Answer could be improved with an example